# Whitespace nowrap and float left "bug" in mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm making a web-app and came accross an interesting thing.
So I have a wrapper div with other divs in it. The wrapper has the following formating:

```
#ready{
  height:568px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

their children divs have this:

```
.theme{
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height:568px;
  width:320px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

It works in firefox and chrome, the divs are next to each other as intended. I have to add `float:left` to `.theme` to make it work in Safari. Although when I add `float:left` Mobile Safari will break the divs to new lines.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Any ideas, workarounds?

**[EDIT]**
Added html

```
   <div id="ready">
            <div id="welcome"class="theme active">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="cat"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="minap"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="minecraft"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="padthai"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="orange"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>

            <div id="bszn"class="theme">
              ...
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This could be happening for several reasons. If you post the HTML that will help figure this out.

Comment: @Michael_B added HTML

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you. Testing various methods. First: `overflow: auto`. Let me know if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/w01ckufb/

Comment: It's all staying inline in safari on my ipad.

Comment: So removing the `float:left` keeps everything inline. But you're saying this breaks something else?

Comment: No in Safari float left is needed because it wont stay inline without it. I dont know why but some divs like the first two and the last one wont stay inline.

Comment: If you really want to ensure that these boxes stay inline across all browsers and devices you may want to consider a table layout. Are you open to that?

Comment: it is not that elegant but you may be right, it is much easier

Comment: I've posted an answer using CSS table properties. I hope this works for you. If it doesn't we can try HTML tables, which is old but reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tried variations of `float: left`, `display: inline-block`, `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to get your row to stay in one line, but it always breaks into two lines on one device/browser or another, maybe a table layout will achieve your goal.

You can use either the HTML `<table>` element or CSS `table` properties. In my example below I've gone with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/w01ckufb/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="ready">
        <div id="welcome"class="theme active">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="cat"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="minap"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="minecraft"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="padthai"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="orange"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
        <div id="bszn"class="theme">IMAGE</div>
    </div><!-- end .ready -->
</div><!-- end #container -->
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
   display: table;
   width: 4000px;
   border-spacing: 15px;    
}

#ready{
    display: table-row;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.theme {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 568px;
    width: 820px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

Hope this helps. If you have any questions leave a comment below.